# hurl vs lob vs fling vs catepult

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

Which words can  be used also to mean that something is used to injure someone as in the following example :

"[To lob](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lob_2)" has a meaning involves a trajectory movement. However, I was wondering if it is used strictly in this sense.

[To fling](http://to%20throw%20something%20somewhere%20using%20a%20lot%20of%20force) means to throw something somewhere using a lot of force.

[To catapult](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/catapult_2) means to throw somebody/something or be thrown suddenly and violently through the air

> The guy hurled a pen at the little boy.

---

> The guy lobbed /flung/catapulted a pen at the little boy.

---

> Protesters hurled/lobbed /flung/catapulted stones at the building.

---

> Someone hurled/lobbed /flung/catapulted a rock through the window.

Comment: A good dictionary could answer this question.

Comment: @Mrt - That's true, but you've been around long enough to know that if you included some dictionary definitions in your question, you wouldn't get as many comments like that.

Answer (score 1):

As you surmise, to "lob" something is to throw it in a high arc.

To "fling" something is to throw it with some force, but with a kind of "flicking" motion, so the objects shouldn't be very large or heavy.

To "hurl" is also to throw something with some force, but it implies a much greater distance than "fling", and the objects are usually larger and/or heavier.

Finally, to "catapult" is to fly (or be thrown) through the air as if by an actual catapult.

[image]
<sub>(source: [britannica.com](https://media1.britannica.com/eb-media/34/83934-004-8770E401.jpg))</sub>

I have no references for this, but in my experience "catapult" is more often used to describe the motion of a *person* than an *object*, e.g.

> He catapulted lightly onto the stage and faced the crowd.

If I were to describe the action of the actual missiles launched from a catapult, I would say they were *hurled* (because they heavy, they are thrown with force, and they go some distance).

Comment: Thank you. You accented a subtle difference dictionaries do not mention really. Although there are difference of meaning, in my example sentences are they all correct to use ?

Comment: Well yes but ... if you *throw* a pen at someone it's probably OK but if you *hurl* a pen then it sounds like you really want to hurt them.

Comment: ...and you likely wouldn't say that you had **catapulted** a pen unless you had used some kind of device to throw it, like a [flexible plastic spoon](http://thrivinghomeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IMG_55661-1024x768.jpg).

Comment: @Mrt - Normally words like _lob_ and _toss_ imply throwing gently, with a high arc. If you're trying to show an intent to injure, use _hurl_ or _throw_ instead.